# Set invalid variable values while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

I am aware of changing variable values in the debug mode by right clicking and setting the desired value.

I need to set an alpha-numeric value to a `long` variable to intentionally throw an exception. The `Variable` window does not let setting an invalid value (for obvious reason).

Is there a way to set, say, `long temp = 12asdf` during debugging?

Currently I am just throwing a `NumberFormatException` forcefully to check the intended behaviour.

Comment: No. I don't think there is a way!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for `NumberFormatException` change the String value that's going to be formatted into a long.

You can't change a `long` into an `String`.

Answer (score 0):

How would that be possible? You can certainly Convert such a String, but a long is guaranteed to not have those values in it (you can cast chars to numbers, but they are guaranteed to be interpreted as numbers). You don't need to test your program for such problems, they can not occurr. Conversions and casts can go wrong, but that's something different from what you are trying to do.